# ExtJS: How to customise the combobox picker's keynav?

Tags: javascript, extjs

A combobox has a picker (a boundlist instance) which itself has a `keynav (BoundListKeyNav)`.

How can I modify / customise this `keynav` instance?

Basically, by default it contains bindings for home / end. While this would be useful under normal circumstances, it is not when using a customised combobox. I want my home / end keys to function correctly, as they do before ext decides to hijack them (go to start / end of input contents).

Ideally, I want to do this in the configuration object of the combobx, like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    itemId: 'search',
    emptyText: 'Search',
    editable: true,
    typeAhead: false,
    hideTrigger: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    minChars: 3,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'search'
}
```

It is made to behave in such a way that you can type anything in (to search) but can also choose auto completed searches.

The `keynav` lives at `combo.listKeyNav`, but the chunk of code which sets this up in ext fires no events to let us jump in and change it. It appears the combo has no configuration for such a thing either (seeing as the function setting listKeyNav doesn't take any config from our combo object).

**FYI**

It is the `BoundListKeyNav` which has these bindings hard coded. The combobox's `onExpand` creates the instance (taking no config anywhere, allowing for no customisation).

Comment: As far as I remember key natigations belogs to SelectionModel, maybe you only need to add a custom SelectionModel

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to override `onExpand` method of combo.

Answer (score 0):

As [Saki wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394770) customizing of the key navigation is only possible with overriding the onExpand method of the combobox - basically duplicating the original implementation (in case of ExtJS4).

For example:

```js
onExpand: function() {
  var me = this,
    keyNav = me.listKeyNav,
    selectOnTab = me.selectOnTab,
    picker = me.getPicker();

  // Handle BoundList navigation from the input field. Insert a tab listener specially to enable selectOnTab.
  if (keyNav) {
    keyNav.enable();
  } else {
    keyNav = me.listKeyNav = new Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav(me.inputEl, {
      boundList: picker,
      forceKeyDown: true,
      tab: function(e) {
        if (selectOnTab) {
          this.selectHighlighted(e);
          me.triggerBlur();
        }
        // Tab key event is allowed to propagate to field
        return true;
      },
      enter: function(e) {
        var selModel = picker.getSelectionModel(),
          count = selModel.getCount();

        this.selectHighlighted(e);

        // Handle the case where the highlighted item is already selected
        // In this case, the change event won't fire, so just collapse
        if (!me.multiSelect && count === selModel.getCount()) {
          me.collapse();
        }
      },
      home: {
        fn: Ext.emptyFn,
        defaultEventAction: false
      },
      end: {
        fn: Ext.emptyFn,
        defaultEventAction: false
      }
    });
  }

  // While list is expanded, stop tab monitoring from Ext.form.field.Trigger so it doesn't short-circuit selectOnTab
  if (selectOnTab) {
    me.ignoreMonitorTab = true;
  }

  Ext.defer(keyNav.enable, 1, keyNav); //wait a bit so it doesn't react to the down arrow opening the picker
  me.inputEl.focus();
}
```